# Show each line within a box using \pause and Beamer

Tags: beamer, align, framed, pause

The idea is to section off texts within boxes and not only show each box at a time, but also each line within a box at each time.

I have a framed package and some code to make align work in beamer, but the frame only comes in at the end.

Here is a minimal working example. Ideally, I'd want the box to always appear, but then have the 1, 2, 3 each appear on the next slide.

```
   \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\makeatletter
\let\save@measuring@true\measuring@true
\def\measuring@true{%
  \save@measuring@true
  \def\beamer@sortzero##1{\beamer@ifnextcharospec{\beamer@sortzeroread{##1}}{}}%
  \def\beamer@sortzeroread##1<##2>{}%
  \def\beamer@finalnospec{}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{framed} % for larger fbox

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{framed}
\begin{align*}
1 \\ \pause
2 \\ \pause
3 
\end{align*}
\end{framed}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you looking for something like this:

```
   \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{framed} % for larger fbox

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{framed}
\begin{align*}
\only<1->{ a^2 & = c^2-b^2 }\\ 
\only<2->{ b^2 & = c^2-a^2 }\\ 
\only<3->{ c^2 & = a^2+b^2 }\\ 
\end{align*}
    \end{framed}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The second slide is:

[image]

**Addendum:** In the first attempt I was not attentive to specific od `align` math environment. In such cases `beaner` documentation in section *23.4 Uncovering Tagged Formulas Piecewise* (page 222) suggest to use `uncower` macro:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{framed} % for larger fbox

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Unnumbered set of equations}

    \begin{framed}
\begin{align*}
             a^2 & = c^2-b^2    \\
\uncover<2->{b^2 & = c^2-a^2    \\}
\uncover<3->{c^2 & = a^2+b^2    \\}
\uncover<4->{a^2+b^2 & = c^2  }
\end{align*}
    \end{framed}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Numbered set of equations}

    \begin{framed}
\begin{align}
             a^2 & = c^2-b^2    \\
\uncover<2->{b^2 & = c^2-a^2    \\}
\uncover<3->{c^2 & = a^2+b^2    \\}
\uncover<4->{a^2+b^2 & = c^2    \\}\notag
\end{align}
    \vspace{-2\baselineskip}
    \end{framed}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That does work - thanks! 

If the equations are unbalanced then they move around a bit because that new align hasn't been made yet. How would I fix that?

Comment: @Sat, you are right. `\only` is not right tool. Use of `\uncover` seems to be what you need. See addendum in my answer where in example is also shown how it works with numbered equations.

Comment: that works great. thanks